# jQuery live change problem

Tags: jquery

When I click an element from list, jQuery get class from clicked element and write it in input field. Then value from input need to be written in div#content without any action.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="NewYork">New York</li>
    <li class="Paris">Paris</li>
    <li class="Moscow">Moscow</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="city" value="" />

<div id="content"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li').live('click', function() {
        var select_value = $(this).attr('class');
        $('input#city').val(select_value);
        return false;
    });

    $('input#city').live('change', function() {
        var content = $(this).val();
        $('#content').text(content+' is beautiful city');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('input#city').val(select_value);
```

To this:

```
$('input#city').val(select_value).change();
```

The `change` event is fired when the value changes, usually on textbox `blur` (clicking elsewhere).  You can however, trigger it when needed with `.change()` or `.trigger('change')`, which is what the above code does.

Comment: @Milos - Welcome!  If an answer resolves your issue, make sure to accept it with the checkmark on the left so it closes the question out :)